# Cancel running workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I need a way to stop 100 running workflows.  I know that I can do it manually by clicking the elements in a list and canceling the associated workflow.  However, this would take a while, and I can't spend all day doing that.  I also know there is a way to do this with MS Powershell scripting, but I cannot change the scripting policy to allow scripting, so that is not an option.  Is there any other way to automate this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use Powershell, then only option is to open the site in Designer and remove them.

Hope the suggestion helps!

Comment: Haha, so the one by one option? :)   I do have a problem however.  I am trying to do the manual way for now, and when I cancel the workflow, the status of the option does not change.  The reason I am doing this is because the running workflows are starting to tax the sharepoint server.  If I straight up delete the item, will the corresponding workflow end?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to List Settings, Select Workflows Settings, and Click Remove Workflow, remove all the workflows - that will get rid of everything - if you want the workflow back, return to Designer and republish it.